# Gmail message.getFrom() gives Alias sender instead of person who sent the mail

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

Goal: With my google sheet script I want to read out my generic Gmail account sent messages so that I can see which team member has sent how many e-mails from the team account.

Constraint: Team Account has alias activated. E-Mails are sent on behalf.

Approach: I used message.getFrom() to extract details from the sent messages.
Issue: The output is always the generic account instead of the senders true name.

Request: Can you tell me any code that will read out the "sent by" value from a gmail that was sent on behalf?

Thanks and best regards
Christoph

Comment: I would guess that you would have to have access to their account so that you could determine their aliases.  Without access to their account I'd say it can't be done otherwise what would be the point of using them?

Comment: So the aliases are from users that sent you a message that dont belong to your organization right?

Comment: The sender behind aliases are team colleges from within my organization only. Our team does send out communication only via the generic account. I do own the generic account. I can see the sent on behalf info in the e-mail. I looks like that: Rotkreuz Instrument Ops <genericmail@mycompany.com> (gesendet von myname@mycompany.com). Thus, the desired information (myname@mycompany.com is there. But I'm oblivious in how to extract it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was: `message.getHeader("sender")`
This toke the sender from the `RFC 2822` header
With this, one can get the alias sender from an e-mail
Like

```
From: boss@company.com or info@company.com
Sender: assistant@company.com
```

#### Reference

- [getHeader](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getheadername)